# How to update data in a specific row in SWT Table

Tags: java, swt

How do I update a `TableItem` in a specific row index in a `SWT` `Table`

I load a table full of data, double click it to load them in multiple components and would like to update the information into the same row.

Can someone help me please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to *update* a row, use the `setText()` and `setImage()` methods of the corresponding `TableItem()`.

For example:

```
TableItem item = table.getSelection()[ 0 ]; // assumes a single selected item
item.setText( 1, "update first column" );
// or
item.setText( new String[]{ "col 1 value", "col 2 value" } );
// or, for a single-columned table
item.setText( "updated value" );
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the

```
public TableItem(Table parent, int style, int index)
```

constructor. This lets you specify the row index of the new item.

This is assuming you are just using `Table` and `TableItem` rather than the JFace `TableViewer`.

Comment: I wanted to replace it.  This just moves the original one one row down.  Any suggestions?

Comment: The other answer covers replacing an existing entry